# Maven - How can I deploy only the web files and not build the whole project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, pom.xml

Maven Builds... Okay this is killing me in time.
The Java project we have takes no less than 12 minutes to build, deploy and start Tomcat. For every simple change that I want to be able to do to a file that does NOT require it to be compiled such as every jsp, htm(l), js, etc. web file I am forced to rebuild this project over and over and over. Hours are being eaten up working through this project because I have to shut down the server and build and so forth.

In the past I had used Ant on projects and was able to create a useful bat file that I could quickly execute Ant builds that would only deploy my web file and not have to build the entire project. This saved me so much time when it would only take a couple seconds rather than 10+ minutes.

So the question is...

**How do I use Maven to only deploy my web based files and not rebuild the entire project?** (Point me in the right direction of some sample pom as I'm very new to Maven and have no internal support)

Failure to understand why a -1 rating on a completely valid question from someone who does not understand what Maven can and cannot do. Please clarify the  reason for -1.

Comment: Is it not an option to just use Eclipse for development (hot) deployments? Yes Maven is slow and that is not really going to change. But unless you have some really awkward to build application, then you can just use Eclipse to deploy the application and just have edits to webfiles immediately accessible in the running Tomcat instance.

Comment: Is it that you do a clean each time? If I execute `mvn package`, only some files will change. Also, you can skip tests. Makes development faster. And third, you can implement integration tests, so you don't need to deploy each time you change something. Also think of putting a static web server (nginx, etc.) in front of your application server for serving and testing static content.

Comment: True enough, but I already wonder what in this process is taking so long in the first place. Yes a Maven build can be slow especially when tests are executed, but 12 minutes seems excessive.

Comment: The build process is made up of several sibling projects as well as sub projects. I found the syntax to at least skip the tests in addition to running it in quiet mode so it would not output so much to the screen. Prior to the changes I have mentioned the process use to take over 15 minutes. Time is critical and I have no options to setup any static servers and add more levels to this mess of a project. @Ben when you say integration tests what do you mean? @ Gimby I am not familiar with Maven at all from what I can see they have build scripts calling Maven and custom Ant builds.

Comment: @Elijah Integration tests will not just run junit tests, but first deploy to a locally started (integrated) web application server and then run tests against http://localhost:8080/project/ using httpget and httppost, and parse the output. This way you don't need to transfer files, which may take long (depending on the network connection).

Comment: @Ben to clarify are you saying that this Integration test is how to handle say the testing of a new HTML file or an update JSP file within the project?

Comment: @Gimby you are correct. Sorry I should have stated that. This is deployed as a .war file. Also, as for downloading anything, I am not allowed by policy to download anything from the web on this computer. Anything I need I must do outside of work, put onto a disc, bring it in, have it scanned and then I can put it onto the developer machine. NIGHTMARE.

Comment: Show us your pom.xml files, please. We cannot guess what slows down your setup.

Comment: @Elijah super-hack: take the war that the pom generates and unzip it into the tomcat webapps folder yourself to have a so called "exploded deployment". Then use your bat file to copy the web files to that folder yourself. At least that will ease the pain.

Comment: @Ben the developer system has CD burning Revoked only the sys admin can burn files. Not that it helps at all but there are I believe in total 45 pom files and 3 Ant builds in addition to 17 .bat files that are used.  I was just hoping that there was just some simple put this tag <magicTag>deployWebFiles</magicTag> that I could use.

Comment: @Elijah why not add a tomcat7-maven-plugin and run the code locally? You can then test your web application by using http://localhost:8080/ in your browser.

Comment: @Elijah there is no magic tag that solves terrible working environments, lack of support and lack of personal knowledge and understanding of the working environment.

Comment: I will need to download that tomcat7-maven-plugin tonight after going home as I cannot do it here at work. Also, I am running it on a locally installed Tomcat (everything is inside of a VM).

Comment: @Gimby ROFL. When I took this position we were slated to hire on a team, be sent out to training and embrace the technology that was in this project. However, 3 weeks into it, budget cut the other 3 developers were let go, no training and a year of agony. All I can do is ask out here in the forums for input and guidance on these things as I know that I have no support here. Thank you both though for your input it is much appreciated.

Comment: @Gimby I just want to clarify this. You guys are saying; there is no way in Maven to have a build process just push out only the modified files from a web folder to a targeted folder such as Tomcat webapps/projectX?

Comment: @Elijah I can't answer that, if I say no some random plugin will magically appear. I suggest you google that, I have never had a need (because I would create a custom ant task for it and call that from the Maven build if I were in your situation). But the difference between you and me is that I took the time to understand Maven before I jumped into projects that used it. Took me a few days to read the book I had, then Maven was my best friend.

Comment: @Gimby actually you did answer the question. I was unaware of creating an ant task in Maven. As for jumping into the project it was more like thrown into it and the only other person who was on it at the time did not know it either. He just showed me the bat files that had been setup a year prior to execute everything. But out of curiosity which book did you choose and would you recommend it? I am starting my own project at home and the concept of Maven seems fairly sound I just need to get a firm understanding of what I'm dealing with rather than bits and pieces off the web.

Comment: @Gimby if you would, please post your comment on the use of ANT as the answer so you can get credit for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Gimby

> create a custom ant task for it and call that from the Maven build

Now doing that is something I have to figure out how to do but at least it is something that can be done and will solve my issue.